# Destructuring object REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started with REACT. I am working with a few graphs and each graph has a few radio buttons. Now depending upon which graph's radio button is clicked, I update the data on that graph. Here is a snippet of the handler function

```
 switch (event.target.name) {
  case "speedGraph":
    const speedGraph = {
      dataSet: graphData["speedGraph"]["dataSet"],
      selectedParam: event.target.value,
    };

    setgraphData({
      ...graphData,
      speedGraph,
    });
    break;

  case "distanceGraph":
    const distanceGraph = {
      dataSet: graphData["distanceGraph"]["dataSet"],
      selectedParam: event.target.value,
    };
    
    setgraphData({
      ...graphData,
      distanceGraph,
    });
    break;
}
```

and the graphData object is as follows. There are a lot of other graphs in graphdata object

```
graphData = {

speedGraph:{dataset:{}, selectedParam: "someValue"},
distanceGraph:{dataset:{}, selectedParam: "someValue"}

}
```

I can see there is a pattern here and I am repeating a lot of things. This is because I have to hard-code the selected graph's data while de-structuring in **setgraphData**. Can you please suggest how I can use the graphName directly instead of hardCoding it?

Comment: `setgraphData({ ...graphData, [name]: { dataSet: graphData[name].dataSet, selectedParam: value } })`?

Comment: thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.target.name` to get the item from the `graphData` object. I find it helpful to give it a more meaningful name first.

The `switch` is then no longer needed, with the assumption that `event.target.name` always can be found in `graphData`.

Here is how:

```
const graphType = event.target.name;
const graphItem = {
  dataSet: graphData[graphType].dataSet,
  selectedParam: event.target.value,
};
setgraphData({
  ...graphData,
  [graphType]: graphItem,
});
```

Comment: shoudln't there be a key stating which graph's object I am modifying?

Comment: That is the `[graphType]:` part

Answer (score -1):

If i'm understanding your question correctly, you could simpy pass in the name of your graph like such.
e.g.

```
case "distanceGraph":
const distanceGraph = {
  dataSet: graphData[event.target.name]["dataSet"],
  selectedParam: event.target.value,
};
```

Comment: no, you are still harcoding the graph's name. jonsarpe's answer is what solved it.